# Can this be done? Bash script in a web application

Tags: bash, tomcat, web-applications, war

I have a bash script (supports linux/unix), that installs an application.
Instead of executing the script in the terminal, I want to deploy it as a web application.

I want to make a web graphical interface for this script, so that the user can give the necessary inputs in the web forms and when ready,then pass these variables into  the bash script to be executed.

This script obvious needs root privileges.

I plan to make it with with tomcat 7 / servlet / jsp. I want to deploy it as .war file.

First, can this be done? Is it possible?

Second, is there any example? I didn't find anything.

Third, any alternative method/better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try tomcat's own CGI support.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cgi-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's possible, but keep in mind that sanitizing user input is hard.

What you want to do is use a scripting language or framework (I recommend sinatra), and use a html form to pass arguments to the backend. In the backend, you call your script by passing whatever arguments you want.

Example with [sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/):

```
post '/whatever' do
  # This is dangerous!
  `myscript #{params[...]}`
end
```

Comment: The original script waits for user's input.I want to remake the script,so that instead of waiting user's input,use the variables values given from the form

Answer (score 0):

Err, but you want this to run on the client side, right?

So you don't really run it as bash on your system, you just template it within your web framework.

If the browser can then display this, it won't just d/l as a file, so you will need to set up a *Content-Disposition: attachment* header in the response to force a d/l.

You will naturally need the user's cooperation to run this as root on his or her system...

Comment: Yes exactly.But i don't understand what do you say exactly ,"you will need to set up a Content-Disposition: attachment header in the response to force a d/l."???